# How to change context path in java file

Tags: java, contextpath

i have `signature.java` file . It is having an init method. Here i need to change static context path to dynamic contextpath. 
Here `myweb` is the contextpath.

`private void init() {
    setHost("/myweb/startApplication.do");
}`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does signature extend HttpServlet?

Comment: So what is your environment... from where do you expect retrieving the path ???

Comment: i am using struts and jsp's. form my application context path. with out mentioning manually as `/myweb/`.